# JOIN and SubQuery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `address` and `actor`. I have to Update the **address**(column in `address` table) of actor whose actor_id(in `actor` table) is 36.

Will the following queries do the same?

USING JOIN:

```
UPDATE `address` 
INNER JOIN actor ON actor.address_id=address.address_id 
SET `address`="677 Jazz Street"
WHERE actor.actor_id=36
```

USING SUBQUERY:

```
UPDATE address
SET address = "677 Jazz Street"
WHERE
    (SELECT address_id FROM actor
        WHERE actor_id = 36);
```

The thing why I am asking for is when I executed subquery, it showed 620 rows affected, where as Join query then showed only 1 matched 0 affected ( this is understood because i already updated using subquery) but why that showed 620?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you're not correlating the subquery with the main table. You need a comparison in the `WHERE` condition.

```
UPDATE address
SET address = '677 Jazz Street'
WHERE address_id = (
    SELECT address_id
    FROM actor
    WHERE actor_id = 36)
```